# Using ANOVA to analyse a distribution

Tags: distributions, anova, methodology

I found a method in an paper, which I do not quite understand. In this experiment the influence of a within subject factor was analysed. In order to analyse the influence of the factor not only on general parameters, such as mean or standard deviation, but on the whole distribution a method was used that I cannot find in the literature. For this the data was sorted into quartiles and the the average for each quartile was calculated. Then using these averages, a standard ANOVA was calculated using the within-subject factor as well as the quartile number was performed.

The only article I could find, which includes something similar is [this one](http://dces.essex.ac.uk/staff/poli/BCI-Mouse/better-averages/ERP-RT-binning/). However, as I am not really familiar with fmrt and similar techniques, I do not understand most of this article and cannot be sure if it actually describes the method I am looking for.

Is this method common for analysing data distributions? If so, where can I find some references explaining this method and how to interpret the results?